# React server side rendering on API port instead of client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app, server-side-rendering

I have a react app I built with an express API to interact with mongoDB. I am now trying to set up server side rendering in my `server.js` file. I can't figure out why but the server rendered string is only being sent in the browser over my API port `localhost:3899/api` instead of `localhost:3000` where my client is being served.

When I `curl http://localhost:3899` I get the html string in my console. When I `curl http://localhost:3000` I get the `public/index.html` skeleton.

I have my client and server directories next to each other at the same level.

- node_modules
- react-ui
- server
- ...

server.js:

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import React from 'react';
import 'ignore-styles';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import render from './render';
import App from '../react-ui/src/App';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import Appointment from './model/appointments';

//and create our instances
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../react-ui/build/static')));
//set our port to either a predetermined port number if you have set 
//it up, or 3899
var port = process.env.PORT || 3899;
//db config
mongoose.connect('mongodb://josh11:josh11@ds133162.mlab.com:33162/heroku_tl016m5d');
app.use(cors());
//now we should configure the API to use bodyParser and look for 
//JSON data in the request body
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//now we can set the route path & initialize the API
router.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.render(
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <header>
            <title>My Universal App</title>
        </header>
        <body>
            <div id='app'>${ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />)}</div>
            <script src='bundle.js'></script>
        </body>
    </html>
  );
});


//Use our router configuration when we call /api
app.use('/api', router);
//starts the server and listens for requests
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('api running on port' + port);
});
//adding the /appointments route to our /api router
router.route('/appointments')
  //retrieve all appointments from the database
  .get(function(request, response) {
    //looks at our Appointment Schema
    Appointment.find(function(error, appointments) {
      if (error)
        response.send(error);
      //responds with a json object of our database appointments.
      response.json(appointments)
    });
  })
  //post new appointment to the database
  .post(function(request, response) {
    var appointment = new Appointment();
    //body parser lets us use the req.body
    appointment.appointmentTitle = req.body.appointmentTitle;
    appointment.appointmentDate = req.body.appointmentDate;
    appointment.appointmentTime = req.body.appointmentTime;
    appointment.appointmentDescription = req.body.appointmentDescription;
    appointment.appointmentDestination = req.body.appointmentDestination;
    appointment.appointmentOrigin = req.body.appointmentOrigin;
    appointment.travelMode = req.body.travelMode;
    appointment.save(function(error) {
    if (error) 
      response.send(error);
      response.json({ message: 'Appointment successfully added!' });
    });
  });
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you environment variable `PORT` ?

Comment: I have `var port = process.env.PORT || 3899;` set for my API.

Comment: But, you have to set environment variable before executing the program. e.g. run this `PORT=3000 node server.js`

Comment: When I run it like that the server fires up like normal in the console except on port 3000 which I would expect from the command. But then my browser Cannot GET/ 404 errors. What should I expect to happen there?

Answer (score 0):

To run the application on port defined by environment, try

```
PORT=3000 node server.js
```

You have other issue in your code. You have defined the router and mounting the router `/api` by defining `app.use('/api', router)`. Hence, you are getting `404` whenever you access http://localhost:3000.

To fix the issue, change the router mounting to `api.use('/', router)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your API and front-end on the same port by replacing `react-scripts` with `react-app-tools` - a slightly altered version of Create React App that adds support for server-side code.

Find more info here: https://github.com/kriasoft/react-app